# Two spaceships are accelerating equally, uniformly on exactly parallel tracks. Does a rope suspended between them eventually rip?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

This question is a variant of "[Bell's spaceships problem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Bell%27s%22+%22spaceship%22)". Rather than one spaceship following the other "on the same track", let the two spaceships accelerate "side by side", on exactly parallel tracks.

Specificly, let the bows (tips) of both spaceships

- be initially at rest to each other, on starting pads with separation $L > 0$, and
- start moving simultaneously with equal constant acceleration $\mathbf a$, undergoing hyperbolic motion on exactly parallel tracks perpendicular to the (initial) separation vector between the two starting pads,
- in an (otherwise as good as) flat region.

From one spaceship bow to the other there is a rope suspended which is strong enough to easily withstand the stresses at the start of the spaceships; but which is guaranteed to have ripped

- if it had been suspended instead over a separation of $10~L$ (while the suspension points started accelerating with $\mathbf a$), or
- if the two suspension points had instead accelerated with constant $10~\mathbf a$ (with initial separation $L$).

Does the rope rip eventually, as the two spaceships continue their hyperbolic motion on exactly parallel tracks?